# Extract java code from image (with tesseract ?)

Tags: programming-languages, ocr, tesseract

I try to extract Java code stored in images of a PDF file.

I already tried to use Tesseract, but it looks like the special characters as * {... does not match very well with the english language, because my output file is pretty inconsistent.

Actually, I can recognize some extracts of the Java code, but mostly, the text is corrupted.

So I wondered if one among you know for example a language extension for Tesseract, or another OCR software which can extract my Java Code.

Thank you for your help :-).

Comment: I have OCR software that has special dictionaries for a few programming languages, including C++ that I think will work for your text type. How many pages do you need to process?

Comment: It should make it ! I've got 9 pages.

Comment: Post an example page.

Answer (score 0):

Quality of OCR depends on the quality of images, no doubt, but also on the technology used, especially on images that are less than perfect.  Also as the complexity of images goes up (formatting, specialized fonts, specific text structures, etc.) the strength of the OCR software gets pressure tested even further.

For a programming language, with a ton of special characters and a more complex line structure than just a typical paragraph of text would be, some OCR programs will have specialized processing modes.  For example, in ABBYY OCR, you can actually select one of several included programming languages (C++, Java, etc.) to enhance the recognition quality.

For your images, I'll be glad to just process them for you through the software I already have.  Send me your pages privately.  I can be reached at ilyae at wisetrend dot com.  It should take a few short minutes.

Alternatively, if you would like to do it yourself for free and without getting any OCR software licenses, or may have need to process more in the future, you can use OCR-IT Web API ([www.ocr-it.com](http://www.ocr-it.com)) and sign up for a free account.  It is API so it will need a few lines of scripting, or you can use Fiddler to make a web request.  The list of languages is here (http://www.ocr-it.com/ocr-cloud-2-0-api/documentation) (see bottom of the page), and use "Java" language for your OCR request.

Comment: Best scan settings for OCR are 300 dpi, or 400 dpi if the font size is small.